# How to modify source android when I attach the source

Tags: android, eclipse, android-webview

I want to change some functionality in the WebView control, is there any way to change the source of the sdk. knowing that I got the source code android.jar and I attach it to eclipse for debugging but I can't edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there any way to change the source of the sdk.

There is no "source of the sdk".

The source code is called an "operating system". It runs as firmware on a device. You can change this code and create replacement firmware which you can load on a device.

Comment: I download the source code of android-sdk-2.2_r1-src.jar I can navigate to the source code when I debug but I can not change it.

Comment: @hicham: If you want to build your own firmware, full instructions are at http://source.android.com.

Answer (score 2):

What about extending WebView via inheretance and implementing functionality in subclass? Editing android sources is unlikely a best practices :)

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I want to delete the toast "text copied to clipboard" and keep the selection to display the contextmenu to perform many actions on the selected text

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the git-hub phonegap source files - https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-android

You can download the source, edit them however you like and then make a jar file.